# Does setting Property of Log4jContextSelector make any difference

Tags: java, logging, configuration, performance-testing, log4j2

I am currently exploring the logging framework log4j 2.
I had configured my log4j2 without setting the property of

> Log4jContextSelector

I had not added the disruptor jar in my build path.

Later on reading the documentation in detail, I came across this statement.

> Don't forget to set system property
>   -DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector
>   to make all loggers asynchronous

When I set this property and added the disruptor jar, I didn't see any significant performance improvement.

I did that by adding below line as the first line in main method.

```
System.setProperty("Log4jContextSelector",
                "org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector");
```

The total amount of logs that I generated during this test is 47.3 MB

This made me think weather setting this property does make any difference?
Or it is by default Asynchronous when using Log4j2.

I am using the following jars:
1. log4j-api-2.8.2.jar
2. log4j-core-2.8.2.jar
3. disruptor 3.2.0.jar

**UPDATE:**
executed the benchmark.jar in log4j2-perf. It starts printing the metrics. I am not able to understand how can I use the metrics to compare it against the synchronous loggers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log4j2 is synchronous by default. The system property that you mention has the effect that all loggers become asynchronous.

What you're doing seems correct. You mention you couldn't see how performance was impacted but it's unclear how you were trying to measure this.

The benefits of asynchronous logging with the Disruptor become more visible when your application has multiple threads that log a lot at the same time, or when you need to log many messages in bursts. Async logging means that your application doesn't need to wait for log message formatting and I/O to complete before doing other work.

Measuring performance is not easy but worth investing time in if your application needs to be able to scale. The [Log4j2 performance](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html) page has links to methodologies and techniques as well as performance test code.

Answer (score 0):

`Log4j` got initialized before calling the `main method`.
So it's unable to pick your property `Log4jContextSelector` from the system and by default, it works synchronously.

To verify same: 
remove `disruptor` dependency, If your project is still going up then it's not getting async.

If you add property via 
-`DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector` 
then after removing disruptor project will not go up.

If you are using tomcat then add system properties in `catalina.properties`. And don't forget to use `immediateFlush="false"`.